# Django page not fund for generic View

Tags: django

Why I am getting page not found error. I passed the views in my urls.py. here is my code:

```
class JsonListView(View):
      def get(self, *args,**kwargs):
          customer_project = list(CustomerProject.objects.values())

          return JsonResponse({'data':customer_project},safe=False)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
              #my others urls.... 
              path('json-data/', JsonListView.as_view(), name='json-data'),
             
            ]
```

my home page and others page haven't any problems. Only getting the Page not found (404) error for json-data page.

console error:

```
Not Found: /json-data/
[04/Aug/2021 03:27:50] "GET /json-data/ HTTP/1.1" 404 6958
```

Comment: Are your `urls.py` the "top level" (root) `urls`, or are these `include(...)`d?

Comment: Willem Van Onsem yes it connected with root url and I also have others url in the same urls.py file those haven't any problems.

Comment: can you please show the top level `urlpatterns`? Likely there is a pattern before (for example with a slug), that is fired since it is ordered before the `json-data/` url pattern.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem can you please tell me what do you mean by  top level ? are you want to see my app url or root url?

Comment: please just share the `urls.py` you wrote...

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks. You are right. It's working after move the url .

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem why it was not working after slug url. before it was look like this `path('<slug:slug>/', UserProfileUpdate.as_view(), name='update-profile'),path('json-data/', JsonListView.as_view(), name='json-data'),`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235600/discussion-between-boyenec-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: Because Django enumerates over the patterns top to bottom, and the first pattern that matches is the view that will run. Now if `<slug:slug>/` is used, then `json-data` matches with that `<slug:...>` pattern, so it will run *the `UserProfileUpdate` view, not the `JsonListView`.